# C# - Entity Framework enable FK with SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, sqlite, foreign-keys

I'm working in a Entity Framework + SQLite app, and i don't know how activate **PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1** in the Model for C# application.

Here my model (My_model.Context.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class My_Model : DbContext
{
    public My_Model()
       : base("name=My_Model")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<My_TABLE1> My_TABLE1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<My_TABLE2> My_TABLE2 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<My_TABLE3> My_TABLE3 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<My_TABLE4> My_TABLE4 { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea?

I have tried modify App.conf doesn't works.
I have found many examples but no works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your App.Config file, add "foreign keys=true" to the connection string, like this:

```
data source=c:\wherever\whatever.sqlite;DateTimeFormat=InvariantCulture;foreign keys=true
```